# Open source blogging

Tags: open-source, blogs

please guys i need an open source blogging software with wide support,extesion, plugin etc. And preferably in php and that can be installed in xampp. i need it for my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard about [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)?

Wordpress is very mature, widely supported, extensible, supports plugins and themes, and is in PHP. Seems to perfectly match your description.

Google tells me another popular choice is [Serendipity](http://s9y.org/).

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you don't want 'heavy', then write one yourself; it's not difficult.

Comment: @ Delan Azabani your comment is not helpful. help if you can

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)
- [b2evolution](http://b2evolution.net/)
- [LifeType](http://lifetype.net/)
- [MovableType](http://movabletype.org/)

The canonical choice is Wordpress, widely adopted and with a lot of extensions.